# Query inserts more records than expected from a JSON file SQL Server

Tags: sql, json, sql-server

I am inserting data from a JSON file. In the JSON file, a key has 3 value items. The problem I have is that instead of inserting the 3 that it actually goes through with the cross aply, it inserts me 18 records (and not 3, one for cookie, one for third and other for log).

The `whatsapp .json` file is:

```
{
 "name_service": "WhatsApp",
 "source": "https://www.whatsapp .com/legal/?doc=version=20120707",
 "industry_name": "Unknow",
 "subindustry_name": "Unknow",
 "version_date": "27/01/2020",
 "category_track": [
    "Cookie",
    "Third",
    "Log"
  ]
}
```

And the SQL Server query I had was this:

```
Declare @JSON VARCHAR(max)
SELECT @JSON = BulkColumn
FROM OPENROWSET (BULK 'C:\User\Desktop\whatsapp.json', SINGLE_CLOB) import

INSERT INTO DATAS(pol_id, service_name, source, parsed_version_url, version_date, data)
select 4, service_name, source, parsed_version_url, version_date, data
  from OPENJSON (@JSON)
  cross apply openjson (@JSON) with (
         service_name VARCHAR (50) '$.name_service',
         source VARCHAR (50) '$.source',
         parsed_version_url VARCHAR (100) '$.source',
         version_date DATE '$.version_date'
         )
  cross apply openjson (@JSON, '$."category_track"') with (
         data varchar (50) '$'
         );
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason for this unexpected result is the fact, that `OPENJSON()` with a default schema (without the `WITH` clause) returns rows for each first-level `key\value` pair (6 in your case) and the second `APPLY` operator with `OPENJSON()` and an explicit schema operator returns a row for each item in the `$.category_track` JSON array (3 in your case).

What you need is a different statement using `AS JSON` and only one `APPLY` operator. Also consider parsing the dates as `varchar` in the `WITH` clause and convert the parsed dates with `TRY_CONVERT()` and the correct date style:

```
INSERT INTO DATAS(pol_id, service_name, source, parsed_version_url, version_date, data)
select 4, service_name, source, parsed_version_url, TRY_CONVERT(date, version_date, 103) AS version_date, data
from OPENJSON (@json) with (
   service_name VARCHAR (50) '$.name_service',
   source VARCHAR (50) '$.source',
   parsed_version_url VARCHAR (100) '$.source',
   version_date varchar(10) '$.version_date',
   categories nvarchar(max) '$.category_track' AS JSON
) j1
cross apply openjson (j1.categories) with (
   data varchar (50) '$'
) j2
```